# Why the exclamation mark appears in front of the text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I just populate `TextBlock` with some text which has ! (exclamation mark) at the end. And ! appears in front of the text.

So instead of

> some text!

I see

> !some
>   text

How is it possible?

Any clue?

Thank you!

---

CODE

```
  TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();

  tb.Text = Text;

  lstItems.Children.Add(tb); // lstItems is a StackPanel
```

Comment: Is it something to do with the application's culture settings?

Comment: You are going to have to post some more code that allows us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you show how Text is populated?

Comment: Is `!` in a TextBlock by itself, or is `!` in the string `Text`?

Comment: @mattytommo Yes I use a lot of cultures.. Will check it now...

Comment: @agent-j It is like this: "any any text and here!"

Comment: @jwismar The Text is populating from some database filed (varchar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, an ancestor of the `TextBlock` has its `FlowDirection` set to `RightToLeft`. Try resetting it to `LeftToRight`:

```
tb.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
```

**Edit**: The reason is a bit complex to explain; it has to do with how [bi-directional text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text) is rendered. From Wikipedia:

> Punctuation characters […] can appear in both LTR and RTL scripts. They are called "weak" characters because they do not contain any directional information. So it is up to the software to decide in which direction these "weak" characters will be placed.

WPF is treating your `!` as separate from the rest of the text, and placing it such that it follows your direction’s flow (in this case, to the <strike>right</strike> left).

Comment: @Peretz: Because you have strange localization settings. :P

Comment: @KendallFrey hehehehehe yeah... spanish... :)

Comment: @Peretz: AFAIK, Spanish is left-to-right (like all other European languages). You might have something configured incorrectly if your app is defaulting to right-to-left for Spanish.

Comment: Probably it happens because of the StackPanel which is owner of TextBlock's. In fact it is a marquee control.